# Measure energy consumed by a python script in Raspberry Pi (Raspbian)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, energy

I have been using pyRAPL on an Intel based computer for measuring energy on a Python encripting program, I wanted to port code to a Raspberry Pi, but I found that ARM does not provide interfaces to this API. Can anyone point me to some direction, method, API to use? Need to measure Joules between an start point and an endpoint in the code.
Thanks!